# How to check if a generic parameter is dynamic in .NET 4.0

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

I have a class `ObjectMapper<T>` . Is there any way in .NET 4.0 to tell if `typeof(T)` is `dynamic`? I want to be able to determine inside a member method whether the class was initialized as `new ObjectMapper<dynamic>()` vs. `new ObjectMapper<SomeConcreteClass>()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do this by checking if an instance is of type `IDynamicMetaObjectProvider` or you can check whether the type implements `IDynamicMetaObjectProvider`.

Comment: This only works if you have an object instance. typeof(T).GetInterfaces() returns a 0-length array.

Comment: This checks if an instance is a dynamic object, but the OP wants to know if the type parameter of the class was set to dynamic.

Comment: There are no dynamic objects: all objects can be referenced via `dynamic`.

Answer (score 10):

There is no CLR type called `dynamic`. The C# compiler makes all dynamic values of type `object` and then calls custom binding code to figure out how to handle them. If `dynamic` was used, it will show up as `Object`.

Comment: Yes, I can see that with a debugger. But is there a way to tell the difference between new ObjectMapper{object}() vs new ObjectMapper{dynamic}()?

Comment: No, you can't tell the difference in your code because the only difference is in how it's used.

Comment: Which IMO was a horrible design decision by the C# team, as C# now enters Java-land where Reflection just can't do some things.
Using a modopt instead of attribute would have been a much better choice.

Comment: @Daniel: You can disable the use of the `dynamic` keyword on a project level, which is a good thing to do for most C# projects IMO.

Comment: Daniel: There are already things Reflection can't do, like emulate Perl's `wantarray`, which can tell you what type the caller expects you to return.