# Detecting dynamic type in code?

Tags: c#, dynamic, methods, syntax

I have a method that takes a generic type, performs a rest query against an API and returns a serialized object.

It works great, but, I want to extend this in order to create dynamic objects when calling APIs that there isn't a predefined type.

I have this working with the only change being a custom deserializer, however, I had to basically copy/paste my method with a different name as I couldn't work out a way of detecting the type as dynamic.

A little example:

```
public T PerformQuery<T>()
{
  var deserializer = new JsonDeserializer();
  var res = deserializer.Deserialize<T>(response);
  return res;
}

public Dynamic PerformQueryDynamic()
{
  var deserializer = new DynamicJsonDeserializer();
  var res = deserializer.Deserialize<T>(response);
  return res;
}
```

What I would like:

```
public T PerformQuery<T>()
{
  if(Typeof(T) == Typeof(Dynamic))
       var deserializer = new DynamicJsonDeserializer();         
  else
       var deserializer = new JsonDeserializer();

  var res = deserializer.Deserialize<T>(response);
  return res;
}
```

I've read other posts here and I understand why Typeof doesn't work with Dynamic, but, I was wondering if there is anything that can do what I want here? There are other things in this method such as Oauth calls and similar that would be so much neater if I can keep this as one method.

... Failing a solution, I was thinking of just adding a bool to the constructor, but, seems like a waste if there is an answer.

Comment: How about this way : [How to check if a generic parameter is dynamic in .NET 4.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277419/how-to-check-if-a-generic-parameter-is-dynamic-in-net-4-0) ?

Answer (score 2):

There is no `dynamic` type. It's all syntactic sugar around dynamic call sites. The compiler will replace `dynamic` with `object` underneath.

As I suppose deserializing an `object` (which has no fields) is meaningless, you could work around this by using:

```
public T PerformQuery<T>(string response)
{
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(object))
        return new DynamicJsonDeserializer().Deserialize<T>(response);

    return new JsonDeserializer().Deserialize<T>(response);
}
```

So `PerformQuery<object>` will work the same as `PerformQuery<dynamic>`, but like I said, this shouldn't be an issue.